# Cound divs inside div with Jsoup

Tags: html, automation, jsoup

I have a page where several status can be found. I would like to count all serviceStatus-OK and serviceStatus-DOWN divs on the page. Unfortunately I cannot modify the page, I need to verify all service is up and running. My idea is that, load the page, count all OK status. If 5 service has 5 OK, we are good. If there is any DOWN, we are not ok.

```
Any ideas?

Source code:

    <span id="content">
                    <div class="status">
                        <div class="serviceName">
                            Some name <br />
                            http://blablaservice1
                        </div>
                        <div class="serviceStatus-OK">
                            OK
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="status">
                        <div class="serviceName">
                            Some other name <br />
                            http://blablaservice2
                        </div>
                        <div class="serviceStatus-DOWN">
                            DOWN
                        </div>
                    </div>

My code:
Elements services = doc.select("span#conent");
        Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
        Elements servicesOks = content.getElementsByTag("status");

        int upCounter = 0;
        int downCounter = 0;
        for (Element y : servicesOks) {
            if (y.hasClass("status-OK")) {
                upCounter++;
            }
        }

        for (Element y : servicesOks) {
            if (y.hasAttr("status-DOWN")) {
                downCounter++;
            }
        }


        System.out.println("OK Systems: " + upCounter);
        System.out.println("DOWN Systems: " + upCounter);

My output is:

OK Systems: 0
DOWN Systems: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the number of okays and downs like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
Elements OK = doc.select(".serviceStatus-OK");
Elements down = doc.select(".serviceStatus-DOWN");
System.out.println("OK - " + OK.size());
System.out.println("DOWN - " + down.size());
```

Find all the elements with the names `serviceStatus-OK` and `serviceStatus-DOWN`, and then count the number of items of each kind (`elemnts` is just a `list`).

Comment: Thank you it is working fine! Appreciate it! My locators were bad. I have another div status is serviceStatus-CHECKING as well. When I load the page, all div has Checking and finally every service got the OK or DOWN status and the DOM is refreshed. How can I wait for the end of the checking process? So every servicestatus-CHECKING div should be disappeared. I tried webdriverwait, but it saves one checking all the time. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sounds like your page is dynamic, so I think `jsoup` is not suitalbe for this. Try searching for phantomJS.

Comment: yes, it is dynamic but I need to go with java, jsoup, webdriver. I just need to wait somehow till the dom is changed and count as you mentioned.